# Is it okay or safe to delete debug_kit.sqlite file

Tags: sqlite, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I found out the debug_kit.sqlite file size is now 24MB?

Is their no effect or no conflict in my website, If I delete this file,?

Comment: RTFM https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html

Comment: can i delete it manually?  in the directory where  it was located? @burzum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete it. If you set your debug to false than files will not be generated anymore